# Remote execution iOS UI tests and unit tests without connection to Mac computer

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I have Mac with installed OS X server. We can remotely install iOS app. But we need to run Xcode UI and Unit tests remotely. The problem is that tested devices has connected lightning MFI device and cannot be connected to Xcode computer. Our goal is to run UI and Unit tests remotely and transfer results to server by Air. Could anyone please propose any suggestion how we can do it?

Comment: Why can't the device be connected? What other choice do you have if it *has* to be connected?

Comment: Device cannot be connected to Mac OSX because lightning plug is reserved for MFI device (like Lightning Card Reader). I guess exists some MDM servers which can launch tests (UI and unit remotely) however its could be to use some private api or jailbreak iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got a final answer from Apple:

> I did investigate if there were any workarounds or alternatives to get UI Tests to run without an active connection to Xcode, and unfortunately I found this was not possible. I also investigated if you could run UIAutomation tests wirelessly since Instruments supports collecting data wirelessly. Unfortunately that support does not extend to the Automation instrument, so it is also not possible to run UIAutomation tests without a lightning cable connected.

Comment: I cannot believe Apple hasn't considered MFI in XCTests. I suppose the idea is that you'd have a development build flag which "simulates" the external device.

Comment: We created disk simulator for this purpose but it's not the same. So finally we use to private API in a separate application for unit tests and publish results in web server. However is no possibility to run XCtests for CONNECTED by lightning interface MFI devices in remote mode.